# DOJOでボタンを押すと消えるタグを作る際の ONに関する問題

Tags: javascript

これらのコードを動作させることを目標としています。現段階では特定のタグを消滅を可能にすれば問題ないです。

今後の事を含めた解決も可能である場合は、タグを消滅するボタンに更に登録機能を付けたいと考えています。

★便宜上、下記で記述したリンクにおいてbunndle.jsを作成しており、その記述は今回は問題が多面化するため、削除しています。
また、bunndle.js単体での機能は動作しております。

＜中核コード（今後結合予定）＞
https://qiita.com/dsk_datadog/items/6dfc55f35db24614107d

対処方法などありましたら、よろしくお願いします。

現在参考中のリファレンス
＜中核コード＞
https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modern_dojo/index.html
＜中核コード→実際に動くサンプルコード＞
https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modern_dojo/demo/modern_dojo-parser.html

＜中核コード（今後結合予定）＞
https://qiita.com/dsk_datadog/items/6dfc55f35db24614107d

＜機能実装に従い参考にしている最中のコード達＞
https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dom_functions/index.html
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182364/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-on-of-undefined
https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/using_query/index.html

---

エラーメッセージ

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
    at l (dojo.js.uncompressed.js:8613:13)
    at index.html:45:6
    at ja (dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1164:35)
    at dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1330:6
    at ka (dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1307:5)
    at ha (dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1325:4)
    at r (dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1492:7)
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1745:20)
button.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

demo.css

```
* {
    outline: none !important;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2em;
    font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida Grande,Arial !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    background: white;
    color: #333;
}

button {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-color: #E4F2FF;
    background-image: url("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.4/dijit/themes/claro/form/images/button.png");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #769DC0;
    padding: 2px 8px 4px;
    font-size:1em;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #AFD9FF;
    color: #000000;
}

h1 {
    font-size:1.5em;
}

.break
{
    float:none;
    clear:both;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Web SQL Database</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.13.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body　class="claro">
<input type="text" name="todo" />



<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" name="register" id="Button1">
  <span>登録</span>


</button>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <span id="test">No Todo</span>

  
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- TODOを追加していく -->
  </tbody>
</table>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.13.0/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: 1, async: 1, parseOnLoad: 1"></script>
    <script>
    require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/on","dijit/registry","dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser,dom, domConstruct, on,registry){
    var myClick = function(evt){
        var test = dom.byId("test");
      domConstruct.empty("test");

        };
     
     on(registry.byId("button1"), "click", myClick);
     parser.parse();
        
    });
    </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> on(registry.byId("button1"), "click", myClick);
> parser.parse();
> ```

[`dojo/parser`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/parser.html)の`parser.parse()`が`data-dojo-type`によるWidgetの作成を行うことに注意してください。前行であればまだ`parser.parse()`の実行前なので`button1` Widgetは作成されておらず、もちろん`registry.byId()`で取得することもできません。

```
parser.parse().then(function(){
    on(registry.byId("button1"), "click", myClick);
});
```

と`parser.parse()`の完了を待って実行するのはどうでしょうか。

---

もう１点見逃していました。

> ```html
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.13.0/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: 1, async: 1, parseOnLoad: 1"></script>
> ```

`dojo/parser`ですが、

- `data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: 1"` の指定により暗黙的に開始されています。
- `parser.parse()`により明示的に開始されています。

詳しい挙動は把握していませんが、２つの実行は競合するように思われます。前述の通り、`parser.parse()`の完了後に`on()`を実行したいため、`parseOnLoad: false` とし、`parser.parse()` のみにするのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。本修正を行ったところdojo.js:sourcemap:108 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
    at l (dojo.js:sourcemap:117:10)
    at index.html:45:5
    at l (dojo.js:sourcemap:102:92)
    at then.b.then (dojo.js:sourcemap:104:470)
    at index.html:44:20
    at ja (dojo.js:sourcemap:26:155)
    at dojo.js:sourcemap:26:410
    at ka (dojo.js:sourcemap:26:277)
    at ha (dojo.js:sourcemap:26:352)
    at r (dojo.js:sourcemap:28:468) "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')\n    at l になりました、若干、エラーの内容が変わったように思えます。パーサーに関する知見、共有ありがとうございます。

Comment: @アークGIS系　新入社員 加筆しました、確認ください。